# I need help understanding what the syntax of this particular if statement accomplishes

Tags: c++, if-statement, syntax

Im trying to follow along and break down a the source code for a pacman clone.  There is an if statement that im confused about.

```
void PacMan::queueDirection(Direction dir)
{
    if (!directions.empty())
    {
        if (dir == -directions.front()) //this statement
        {
            std::queue<Direction> clear;
            std::swap(directions, clear);
        }
    }

    if(directions.size() < 2)
        directions.push(dir);
}
```

My question is what does the - infront of -directions.front() do? directions is a queue.  Does it multiply the reference returned by front() by -1?
Thanks for the help - ill post a link below to the github where the whole project is.
https://github.com/HexagonNico/Pac-Man/blob/master/PacMan.cpp if that tickles your fancy.

Comment: _Does it multiply the reference returned by front() by -1?_ In effect, although most people would say that it simply negates the value returned by `front()`.

Comment: `-` is subtraction, not multiplication. In this case it negates the value returned by `directions.front()`, meaning it changes the sign to the opposite of what it was.

Comment: First, thanks for responding so quick.  A follow clarification question, so your saying that the if statement is comparing dir to nothing? or what is it returning to compare? @PaulSanders

Comment: That is the `unary minus` (or negation) operator. You can find its description on [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic).

Comment: ok I understand what it does now but now why I guess.  Why would you want to negate a reference in this manner?

Comment: Presumably that statement is saying "if the direction being queued is the opposite of the first direction in the queue". Put another way: "if the new direction cancels out the first element of the queue".

Comment: `front()` returns a reference the to the first object held in the queue. As far as this code is concerned it is operating on the first object in the queue. If, for example, `front()` returns an `int` of `4` then the if statement is comparing `dir` to `-4`.

Comment: Ah I understand, thank you all for helping I appreciate your time!

Comment: @KenWhite: `-` is neither a subtraction, nor a multiplication. It is just a symbol. Nothing else. Just because it is often used for _subtraction_, does not mean it's subtraction. In this case, it is a **negation**. as you correctly said, but that does not have anything to do with *subtraction*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have pasted seems to have the following intent:
In case the Direction instance at the head of the queue, directions, is a negative of the value supplied as the argument of this function, the queue is cleared and the supplied argument is enqueued.

The type Direction in this case is an enum as defined in the header [Directions.h](https://github.com/HexagonNico/Pac-Man/blob/master/Directions.h)

```
enum Direction
{
    Up = 1,
    Down = -1,
    Left = 2,
    Right = -2,
    Unset = 0
};
```

Negating a Direction instance, in this case, just gives us its diametric opposite.

As an example, consider that the value Direction::Up is at the head of the queue at the time the function is invoked and the argument to the function is Direction::Down. In this case the queue directions will be cleared. I have added an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff74a826f2253960) to make this point clearer.

Comment: Exelent example my friend, thank you for clearing my head. I really appreciate your time helping me.  I'll look at your example next time I sit down to work. Again thanks.